# Storing The Data Collected by Ninja Forms into Another (custom) Database

Tags: plugins, database, forms, plugin-ninja-forms

My objective is to use Ninja Form for data collection at various places all over my website. But once that data is collected, depending on which form it came from and what data has been filled, I want to filter and store it in custom database tables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The data is stored in the wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables. You can see all the field values by doing this:

```
SELECT website from 

(SELECT m1.meta_value as user_firstname, m2.meta_value as user_lastname, m3.meta_value as website
 FROM dev_posts
 join dev_postmeta m1 on m1.post_id = ID and m1.meta_key = '_field_1'
 join dev_postmeta m2 on m2.post_id = ID and m2.meta_key = '_field_2'
 join dev_postmeta m3 on m3.post_id = ID and m3.meta_key = '_field_3'
 where post_type = 'nf_sub') as v1

WHERE user_firstname = 'John' AND user_lastname = 'Allen'
```

The "x" in "_field_x" is the field ID in Ninja Forms.

source: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28910247/Where-is-Ninja-form-data-stored-in-the-WordPress-database.html

Once you get the content, you can store it in any table.

Comment: I dont think this is a correct solution. I want the data to be stored in a custom database table instantly when the user submits the form. I already know where Ninja Form stores form submissions but that isnt helpful. I dont want to shift data between tables after the form has been submitted.